# Macbook 15" Mid-2015 - Wifi Occasionally Slow

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, airport

I am encountering a weird issue regarding the Wi-Fi speeds on my (Apple Refurbished) Macbook 15" Mid-2015. On my home network, sometimes the wifi speeds would be extremely slow. I ran "ping google.com" in terminal and the ping times are >1000ms. The weird thing is that this rarely happens on my school network, only when it is connected to my home network is when this issue begins to arise.

Solutions attempted -

- Switching between 2.4 and 5 Ghz networks. Issue still persists.
- Deleting a .plist file which stores wifi configuration information. Issue still persists.
- Removing the Wi-Fi service in system preferences and added it back in. Issue still persists.

I have also tested if the problem exists on a ethernet connection, and it does not happen on it. Other Wi-Fi connected devices on the network never had this problem, even my old macbook didn't seem to have it aswell.

Macbook Specs -

- Intel Core i7 2.8Ghz
- 16GB 1600Mhz DDR3
- 1TB Flash Storage
- Intel Iris and AMD graphics.
- OSX Sierra 10.12.5

I might go to the apple store and see if it can be fixed there since it is still under warrenty.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of router do you have at home? If the speeds are fine at school, the laptop is probably not the issue.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Linksys WRT1900ACS Dual-Band Gigabit Wifi Router

Comment: Seems like a solid router. Do you live in a large metropolitan area? Sometimes wifi throughput can be higher or lower depending on congestion from other wifi networks nearby.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard I currently live in a small suburb. Here is the list of other wi-fi networks surrounding me at the moment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JmDFe2K.png)

Comment: You can try manually changing channels on your router, and see if that helps things any. For the 2.4GHz band, you should only use channels 1, 6 and 11 (and if you happen to go to Japan, channel 14). You can try any channels on the 5GHz band.